# Linewidth increases when zooming in on vector drawing .NET

Tags: .net, zooming, basic, drawing2d

When zooming in on a vector drawing in Visual Basic .NET, after a certain point the lines get thicker with each zoom action.

App functionality is basically to draw some lines:

- a graphics matrix is set using transformation and scaling to get the whole drawing fill the canvas (using g.Transform = myMatrix)
- lines are drawn (using "g.DrawLine(...)")

... and when zooming in:

- the transformation matrix is adjusted to zoom in on the mouse pointer location
- the scalefactor for the matrix increases by a factor 1.1

The matrix is set in the PrepareDrawing method:

```
Private Function PrepareDrawing(ByRef g As Graphics) As Matrix
    'Create transformation matrix
    Dim myMatrix = New Matrix

    'Determine the zoom factor
    If zoomfactor > 10000 Then zoomfactor = 10000
    If zoomfactor < 0.001 Then zoomfactor = 0.001

    scaleFactor = zoomfactor * BORDERFACTOR * Math.Min(pb.Width / viewportModel.Width, pb.Height / viewportModel.Height)

    'Determine the offset to keep everything centered
    If panningOffset.IsEmpty Then
        ZoomToNetwork()
    End If

    myMatrix.Translate(panningOffset.X, panningOffset.Y)
    myMatrix.Scale(scaleFactor, -scaleFactor, MatrixOrder.Append)

    'transform current graphics
    g.Transform = myMatrix

    Return myMatrix
End Function
```

And the zooming functionality is set in the ZoomInWithMouseWheel method:

```
 Public Sub ZoomInWithMouseWheel(ByVal e As Point, ByVal delta As Single)
    Dim orgZoomfactor = zoomfactor
    Dim screenX As Double = e.X 
    Dim screenY As Double = e.Y 

    If delta > 0 Then
        zoomfactor = zoomfactor * 1.1 
    Else
        zoomfactor = zoomfactor / 1.1 
    End If

    scaleFactor = zoomfactor * BORDERFACTOR * Math.Min(pb.Width / viewportModel.Width, pb.Height / viewportModel.Height)

    Dim perc = zoomfactor / orgZoomfactor
    panningOffset.Offset(-(perc * screenX - screenX) / scaleFactor, (perc * screenY - screenY) / scaleFactor)

End Sub
```

It turns out that when the first element of the matrix becomes larger than 1, the line width increases with this number.

Any thoughts on what is happening and how I can prevend the line width from increasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer. Line width should be compensated for the matrix element(0), e.g.:

```
g.DrawLines(New Pen(Color.Blue, lineWidth / g.Transform.Elements(0)), pnts)
```

where lineWidth is 1 for example